# Increasing the maximum allowable cell limit in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I am trying to retrieve some data from my database and displaying it in excel. One of the field which am extracting is returning a value due to which I am getting the following error:

```
[Macro <ReportData.MessageText> returned 33612 characters which is more than the maximum allowable by Excel (32767). Cell Content has been truncated to 32767 characters.]
```

I dont want the cell content to be truncated as it contains important data. Is there a way by which I can increase the cell limit? I tried merging two cells which didn't work.

Please guide.

Comment: I think you can't. Also have you tried working with an Excel cell which contains 32,767 characters? This is almost impossible. So why such large amount of text data in one Excel cell?

Comment: So many people think that MS-Excel is a database program, while in MS-Office, MS-Access is the database program. Why don't you use MS-Access for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible as this is an Excel limitation. The only thing you could do is splitting the content from Database into two (or if needed more) cells.

Write a function that checks content length and if it is more than 32767 characters put the first 32767 in a cell and the rest (if less than 32767) in another cell or split again.